# Is $G=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}:x+y<4\}$ irreflexive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Let $G=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}:x+y<4\}$
>   Is $G$ irreflexive?

I know $<$ is an irreflexive relation. But how to show it?

How do I do this?

The Reflexive and Irreflexive property always gets me.
We might as well look at other properties too.
I can show G is transitive 
If $x+y<4$ and $y+z<4$. Then $x+z<4$

Answer (score 1):

Since $(1,1) \in G,$ so $G$ is not irreflexive.

Since $(3,3)\notin G,$ so $G$ is not reflexive either.

Since $(1,2),(2,1) \in G$ but $1\neq 2$ so $G$ is not antisymmetric.

$G$ is symmetric because $x+y <4 \implies y+x <4.$

Since $(3,0),(0,3)\in G$ but $(3,3) \notin G,$ so $G$ is not transitive.

You might want to revisit the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Properties) if you're having trouble in proving these properties.

Comment: I don’t under why G is not irreflexive. If (1,1) is in G 2<4 . So G isn’t it

Comment: A relation $R$ is irreflexive if for all $x \in X, (x,x) \notin R.$ Here $1+1<4$ which means $(1,1) \in G$ and so $G$ can't be irreflexive. Irreflexivity in words means that **no** element is related to itself. So if you can find one element which is related to itself, then the relation can't be irreflexive. I **strongly** recommended going through the definitions again.